# Design By Contract in C#3.0

Tags: c#-3.0, design-by-contract

I know that C# 4.0 has the `Code Contract` feature that can be used to implement post-condition and pre-condition. But I am wanting to implement it using C# 3.0 only. I am experimenting to use this feature in my work. Is it possible to use `attributes` to implement post-conditions and pre-conditions?

Any advise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) with C# 3 and .NET 3.5. The main difference is that the core classes (not the tools) are built into .NET 4 already.

Answer (score 0):

I use a mere Debug.Assert instruction for preconditions and postconditions, and I manually write a `bool Invariant()` function, which I call as `Debug.Assert(Invariant())` on entry and exit of relevant/nontrivial public methods.

It's manual work, ok, but it's very easy and you get used to it quickly. Also, it allows me to follow Eiffel's design by contract philosophy very closely.